# Windows Service running as Local System unable to launch Com Server as Interactive User

Tags: windows, windows-7, com, windows-services

I have service (written in c# 4) running as the Local System  user that needs to communicate with a COM Server (written in ATL) that is configured to run as the interactive user. This COM Server then launches a GUI application.

This works on my development machine but fails on our test environment and other developers' machine. On these machines it appears that the COM Server is not being activated at all.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Can confirm that the COM server is being activated as the interactive user on other machines. Communication just doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: Do you have any `HRESULT`s or .NET `ComException`s to show? You've ruled out activation, are you missing a registration step in other machines?  Are you missing some required component in other machines?

Comment: Perhaps a missing DLL dependency, e.g., the C runtime library?  Process Monitor (available from the Microsoft web site) might be a useful diagnostic tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a permission issue. On some of the machines the users did not have launch and activation permissions.

Comment: Thanks @Harry. Fixed that.